# ImageMagick Border

Tags: imagemagick

I'm trying to apply the `Torn Paper Edge` to a **GIF** I created. How can I do so?

Website: https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#torn

Comment: An example is just below your rounded in the same link. See https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#torn

Comment: Oops, I didn't realize I used `Rounded` instead of `Torn`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input:

[image]

Linux or Mac Syntax:

```
convert thumbnail.gif \( +clone -alpha extract -virtual-pixel black -spread 10 -blur 0x3 -threshold 50% -spread 1 -blur 0x.7 \) -alpha off -compose Copy_Opacity -composite torn_paper.png
```

Windows Syntax:

```
convert thumbnail.gif ( +clone -alpha extract -virtual-pixel black -spread 10 -blur 0x3 -threshold 50% -spread 1 -blur 0x.7 ) -alpha off -compose Copy_Opacity -composite torn_paper.png
```

[image]

See https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#torn

Note: For ImageMagick 7, replace convert with magick.

Comment: How would I run this?

Comment: Install ImageMagick if not already on your system. (Linux comes with ImageMagick). Open a terminal window. Go to the directory with your images. Change my input and output gifs to yours in the code. Then just copy the code and paste it into a terminal window. Hit return if it does not do so automatically.

Comment: I probably should have stated in my initial post that I'm a bit of a noob when it comes down to ImageMagick.

Comment: When I paste it into the command prompt, it returns each line. My GIF is on my desktop.

Comment: Are you on Windows PC? If so, the syntax is slightly different. I have edited my post to show both syntaxes. Your copy and paste is not respecting the \ or ^ which are new line characters. So I have removed them so that the command is one long line not multiple lines. Try one of those.

Comment: Sorry for the long response, I am currently on Windows.

Comment: See my edits to my answer for Windows syntax.

Comment: It's still pasting as multiple lines.

Comment: I don't think I'm doing something correctly. I pasted it into to the Command Prompt replacing `thumbnail.gif` with the my GIF `GIF.gif` while on the Desktop directory. It reads back with `Invalid Parameter - (`.

Comment: Could you possibly take me threw step by step on how to accomplish this?

Comment: I don't really understand how to use the commands. This won't even work for me `C:\Users\*****\Desktop>convert wizard.jpg wizard.png
Invalid Parameter - wizard.png`

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot to include `magick` at the beginning.

Comment: For ImageMagick 7, use magick not convert and not magick convert.